Ok to ask this question
Is using a sentence in asking a person that is coming to visit you from another state OK to say like this?
“When are you coming in?”
Or
“When will you all come in?”

How many people are coming?

4 people coming in from out of town to my home.

Doesn’t sound right to end sentence with “in,” and would be more clear to ask, “what day do you drive over,” or when are you all arriving?”
Coming “in” sounds like the answer would only be related to time, like, appropriate answers would be to “when are you all coming in” would be: 1) “in a little while” 2) “on time,” 3) “after 5” etc

I think it would be better to ask "When are you coming over?" or "When are you coming to My Home Town?"

Are you asking when they are visiting you or when they'll arrive in the state/finish their journey (kind of like "when does your flight land?" "when do you get in?")


When are you coming in?

That is understandable. It sounds like something people might say (in general), even though I would prefer:

When are you getting here?
When do you arrive?
When will you arrive?
When does your flight get in?
What time are you getting here?
When will you come over? (That implies they are already in town)

Actually, this sounds familiar - "When are you getting in?".

But it doesn’t sound right to end a sentence with "in"

Why? How about "come over"?
English expressions often end with what appears to be a preposition. On this topic, search for phrasal verbs.  They are like separable German verbs.

come over would not work with "from another state".

@Lambie, that was in reply to ending a sentence with "in", which I imagined was a problem about "ending a sentence with a preposition".

Some uses of come into versus come in.
Come into [a place, building, house or town, city, country etc.] from another geographical place.

Come into New York City from New Rochelle.
Come into New York state from Massachusetts.
Come into Canada from the States.
Come into the house when it's cold.
Come into money. [inherit]
Come into [the building]

Generally, you come into a/one state from another one.
BUT:
The children will come in [enter a place OR arrive at] at 9:00. [They come in from being out or from being outside]
The plane will come in [land] at 5:00.
The man will come in [arrive here] at 5:00.
That guy came in [entered a place] yesterday.
The train came in [arrived] at 2:00.
The Spy Who Came In [to the British Secret Service] From The Cold [famous book]
into means into a physical place. come in can have several meanings. Below are three as used above.
come in=ENTER
come in=ARRIVE
come in=LAND
come in=RETURN FROM BEING OUT [not at home]
